# NSIS: Error in page after abort from page leave function

Tags: installation, nsis

I've an NSIS script to copy a .NET app build and execute some scripts on an SQL DB. I'm using xsqlexecutor tool in nsis to run these scripts after capturing sql details like instance, DB and login. These are populated from the windows registry when the nsis custom page is called. The page leave function checks if it can connect to this DB successfully, and if it can't, it aborts the leave function and comes back to the page.Problem here is, when i give wrong details first time, the leave function aborts and comes back to the page, but if i give correct DB details again, it says xsqlexecutor has stopped functioning. However if go back a page and then hit next and come to the page again it seems to be working if i give correct DB details,

```
    Function SqlConfigPage
         SectionGetFlags ${SEC03} $R0
         IntOp $R0 $R0 & ${SF_SELECTED}
         IntCmp $R0 ${SF_SELECTED} show
         Abort

show:
 nsDialogs::Create /NOUNLOAD 1018
 Pop $Dialog
 ${If} $Dialog == error
  Abort
 ${EndIf}
 ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 15u "Enter SQL Details"
   Pop $Label

   ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 15u 50u 12u "Server Instance"
   Pop $Server

    ${NSD_CreateText} 60u 15u 100% 12u "$instance"
   Pop $instance

   ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 30u 36u 12u "SQL DB"
   Pop $dblabel

   ${NSD_CreateText} 36u 30u 100% 12u "$db"
   Pop $db

   ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 45u 36u 12u "Username"
   Pop $userlabel

   ${NSD_CreateText} 36u 45u 100% 12u "$user"
   Pop $user

   ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 60u 36u 12u "Password"
   Pop $Passwordlabel

   ${NSD_CreatePassword} 36u 60u 100% 12u "$pwd"
   Pop $pwd
                nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd

Function SqlConfigPageLeave

 ${NSD_GetText} $Server $R1
 ${NSD_GetText} $db $R2
 ${NSD_GetText} $user $R3
 ${NSD_GetText} $pwd $R4
 StrCpy $server $R1
 StrCpy $db $R2
 StrCpy $user $R3
 StrCpy $pwd $R4

InitPluginsDir
SetOutPath "$PLUGINSDIR"
SetOverwrite On
  CreateDirectory $PLUGINSDIR\SQL
  SetOutPath "$PLUGINSDIR\SQL"
  File /nonfatal "..\xsql.exe"
  File /nonfatal "..\sqlconnectioncheck.txt"
  nsExec::Exec '$PLUGINSDIR\SQL\xsql.exe /s:$R1 /d:$R2 /t:false /u:$R3 /p:$R4 /m:3 /q /f:"$PLUGINSDIR\SQL\sqlconnectioncheck.txt"'
   IfFileExists $PLUGINSDIR\SQL\ScriptErr.txt sqlerror continue
 sqlerror:
 FileOpen $7 "$PLUGINSDIR\Scripts\ScriptErr.txt" r
 FileRead $7 $8
 FileRead $7 $9
 FileClose $7
  MessageBox MB_OK "SQL Connetion failed, check SQL details provided once again. $8 $9"

continue:
FunctionEnd
```

any input would be helpful, thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: I don't see any calls to Abort in the SqlConfigPageLeave function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, you are rewriting controls handles at -Leave function.:

```
 StrCpy $server $R1
 StrCpy $db $R2
 StrCpy $user $R3
 StrCpy $pwd $R4
```

Thus, at second invoking you always get trash in parameters:

```
 ${NSD_GetText} $Server $R1
 ${NSD_GetText} $db $R2
 ${NSD_GetText} $user $R3
 ${NSD_GetText} $pwd $R4
```

Because $Server,$db,  $user, $pwd  contains previous values instead of control handles.

Use separate variables for controls and its values, something like this:

```
Var server_ctrl
Var db_ctrl
Var user_ctrl
Var pwd_ctrl
     Function SqlConfigPage
             SectionGetFlags ${SEC03} $R0
             IntOp $R0 $R0 & ${SF_SELECTED}
             IntCmp $R0 ${SF_SELECTED} show
             Abort

    show:
 nsDialogs::Create /NOUNLOAD 1018
 Pop $Dialog
 ${If} $Dialog == error
  Abort
 ${EndIf}
 ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 15u "Enter SQL Details"
   Pop $Label

   ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 15u 50u 12u "Server Instance"
   Pop $Server_ctrl

    ${NSD_CreateText} 60u 15u 100% 12u "$instance"
   Pop $instance

   ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 30u 36u 12u "SQL DB"
   Pop $dblabel

   ${NSD_CreateText} 36u 30u 100% 12u "$db"
   Pop $db_ctrl

   ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 45u 36u 12u "Username"
   Pop $userlabel

   ${NSD_CreateText} 36u 45u 100% 12u "$user"
   Pop $user_ctrl

   ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 60u 36u 12u "Password"
   Pop $Passwordlabel

   ${NSD_CreatePassword} 36u 60u 100% 12u "$pwd"
   Pop $pwd_ctrl
                nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd

Function SqlConfigPageLeave

 ${NSD_GetText} $Server_ctrl $R1
 ${NSD_GetText} $db_ctrl $R2
 ${NSD_GetText} $user_ctrl $R3
 ${NSD_GetText} $pwd_ctrl $R4
 StrCpy $server $R1
 StrCpy $db $R2
 StrCpy $user $R3
 StrCpy $pwd $R4

InitPluginsDir
SetOutPath "$PLUGINSDIR"
SetOverwrite On
  CreateDirectory $PLUGINSDIR\SQL
  SetOutPath "$PLUGINSDIR\SQL"
  File /nonfatal "..\xsql.exe"
  File /nonfatal "..\sqlconnectioncheck.txt"
  nsExec::Exec '$PLUGINSDIR\SQL\xsql.exe /s:$R1 /d:$R2 /t:false /u:$R3 /p:$R4 /m:3 /q /f:"$PLUGINSDIR\SQL\sqlconnectioncheck.txt"'
   IfFileExists $PLUGINSDIR\SQL\ScriptErr.txt sqlerror continue
 sqlerror:
 FileOpen $7 "$PLUGINSDIR\Scripts\ScriptErr.txt" r
 FileRead $7 $8
 FileRead $7 $9
 FileClose $7
  MessageBox MB_OK "SQL Connetion failed, check SQL details provided once again. $8 $9"

continue:
FunctionEnd
```